# Efficient way to exchange tree-like json data between frontend (React) and backend (Spring)

Tags: reactjs, json, spring, spring-boot, web-applications

I have a web application where I am trying to visualize directory-like data (=could be nested). The frontend is done in React with PrimeFaces' tree component while the backend is written in Spring and Oracle (relational) is the DB. The communication is through JSON. The app is working but isn't efficient. For example, to delete a single node, I mark the node as 'delete' on the frontend and send the whole tree to the backend, where I loop through each node, check its 'action' field and take an appropriate action (e.g. 'delete', 'add' or 'update'). What are some of non-brute-force ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually better to deal with each node individually, so all of them should have some kind of UUID to pass from/to your API.

That also implies that you should consider loading your tree by levels, like traversing through folders in file manager.
First goes the stuff in "root" and other parts can be loaded on demand.